# Based on html response i have send value of button as well as Id of data to spring controller using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am  using Spring MVC,Angularjs and Mongodb. I am new to this. I have html page where I'm displaying taskname,ownername and accept/reject button. On click of accept or reject button i have to send accept/reject value and along with that I have to send id of the data so that based on id i can update database. But i don't know how to send id of data as well as value of button to spring controller. I have attached the response of html page.

//userNotification.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in taskDetails">
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{task.name}}</td>
                <!-- <td style="text-align: center;">{{task.owners}}</td> -->
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <span ng-repeat="owner in task.owners">{{owner.ownerName.name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
                </td>
                <td  style="text-align:center;">
                    <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" ng-click="approveTask(taskDetails.indexOf(task.id), task)" value="approveTask">Approve</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="rejectTask(taskDetails.indexOf(task.id), task)">Reject</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

*[image: Response I'm getting]

Answer (score 0):

To send data must also use "{{ }}"

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" ng-click="approveTask(taskDetails.indexOf({{task.id}}), task)" value="approveTask">Approve</button>
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="rejectTask(taskDetails.indexOf({{task.id}}), task)">Reject</button>
```

Comment: how can we pass value of button as well as id to controller.js,service.js and spring controller using angularjs?

Comment: In terms of "value of button"? You want to validate that button was pressed? the tag "value" button has referred or relevance?

Answer (score 0):

My friend !

Check existing demo projects on gitHub before writing 'I am new to that...' with simple question.
Check my demo project for example https://github.com/dimylik/my_money_flow/
same technologies

something like that on your question

your HTML:

```
<button ng-click="approveTask(task)" >Approve</button>
<button ng-click="rejectTask(task)">Reject</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.approveTask = function(task) {
  $http.get("/task/approve/"+ task.id).success(function(data) {
     alert("Approved! "+ data);
  });
}

$scope.rejectTask = function(task) {
  $http.get("/task/reject/"+ task.id).success(function(data) {
     alert("Rejected! "+ data);
  });
}
```

Java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/approve/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String loadItem(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    updateTask(id, Status.APPROVE);
    return id;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/task/reject/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String loadItem(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    updateTask(id, Status.REJECT);
    return id;
}

void loadItem(String id, Status){
  // do magic with MongoDB or any DB you want
}

enum Status {
    APPROVE,
    REJECT
}
```

Comment: Why have you used GET method?As we are updating so it should be PUT. Please clearify.

Comment: no differences in this case, because we are not passing any data. but yes, use POST instead. POST is more proper function for that.